# Transformation based on Hero animation progress

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-animation

I want to transform a Flutter widget based on the progress of a Hero animation. 
For example, I'd like to gradually clip an image while moving it to another page (using a Hero animation). In case of using a regular animation, I would just call the `.value` attribute in order to check the progress of the animation and transform the clipper according to that value, but how can I achieve something similar with a Hero animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to listen to the progress of your hero animation to achieve what you are trying to do.

Child of Hero widgets do not have to be the exact same. You can clip one of the widgets, and leave the other one unclipped. The Hero widget will automatically animate the widget from being unclipped to clipped.

Comment: "Child of Hero widgets do not have to be the exact same" - that point was unknown to me! The clipping effect now runs smoothly along the transition!

Comment: @pitazzo Glad that I was able to help you!